# Are "git fetch --tags --force" and "git pull <branch>" conmutative operations?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

Normally the git tags are a fixed reference to a commit. But sometimes they are used to mark some event (`last-build`, `base-line`, etc..) and they change frequently.

I have an script that refreshes those kind of "floating" tags from the reference repository.

```
git fetch --tags --force
```

and also make pull from one branch:

```
git pull origin <mybranch>
```

I know that many git users warn about using floating tags, but i am forced to deal with that. My question is:

*If the branch is marked by one of those floating tags... does the execution order of the commands matter?*

I am afraid that `git pull` doesn't refresh the tags when they exist locally, and that it might work with the reference of the all tags if it runs first.

`git pull` has a `--force` option, but the help section of the option `--no-tags` explain the default behavior as:

> By default, tags that point at objects that are downloaded from the
>   remote repository are fetched and stored locally.

Does it means that the objects should be downloaded first in order to be able to refresh the tags ? In that case `git pull` should go first.

Which is the correct order?

Comment: I *think* I know what you mean by "floating tags" but it seems like it would be good to define it here.

Comment: done. thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This gets into one of the more obscure corners of Git, but in the end the answer is "it doesn't matter initially which order you use".  However, I'd recommend avoiding `git pull` in general, and never using it in scripts anyway.  Plus, it does matter, in a different way, precisely *when* you fetch, as we will see below.  So I'd recommend running your own `git fetch` first, then simply not using `git pull` at all.

#### `git fetch`

A plain `git fetch` (without `--tags`) uses a weird hybrid tag update by default, although each remote can define a default tag option that overrides this default.  The weird hybrid is what you quoted: *tags that point at objects that are downloaded from the remote repository are fetched and stored locally.*  The underlying mechanism for this is a bit tricky and I'll leave that for later.

Adding `--tags` to the `git fetch` arguments has almost the same effect as specifying, on the command line, `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.  (We'll see the difference in a moment.)  Note that this does not have the force flag set in the refspec, yet testing shows that the fetched tags are force-updated anyway.

Adding `--force` has the same effect as setting the force flag in each explicit refspec.  In other words, `git fetch --tags --force` is roughly equivalent to running `git fetch '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'`: if the remote has tag `refs/tags/foo` pointing to commit `1234567...`, your Git will replace any existing `refs/tags/foo` so that you now have your own `refs/tags/foo` also pointing to commit `1234567...`.  (But as observed in practice, it does that even with just `--tags`.)

Note that in *all* cases, `git fetch` writes information about what it fetched to the file `FETCH_HEAD`.  For instance:

```
$ cat .git/FETCH_HEAD
e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c        branch 'master' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
a274e0a036ea886a31f8b216564ab1b4a3142f6c    not-for-merge   branch 'maint' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
c69c2f50cfc0dcd4bcd014c7fd56e344a7c5522f    not-for-merge   branch 'next' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
4e24a51e4d5c19f3fb16d09634811f5c26922c01    not-for-merge   branch 'pu' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
2135c1c06eeb728901f96ac403a8af10e6145065    not-for-merge   branch 'todo' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
```

(from an earlier fetch run without `--tags`, and then):

```
$ git fetch --tags
[fetch messages]
$ cat .git/FETCH_HEAD
cat .git/FETCH_HEAD 
d7dffce1cebde29a0c4b309a79e4345450bf352a        branch 'master' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
a274e0a036ea886a31f8b216564ab1b4a3142f6c    not-for-merge   branch 'maint' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
8553c6e5137d7fde1cda49817bcc035d3ce35aeb    not-for-merge   branch 'next' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
31148811db6039be66eb3d6cbd84af067e0f0e13    not-for-merge   branch 'pu' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
aa3afa0b4ab4f07e6b36f0712fd58229735afddc    not-for-merge   branch 'todo' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86    not-for-merge   tag 'gitgui-0.10.0' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
[much more, snipped]
```

We will come back to this in just a moment.

The fetch may, depending on whatever additional refspecs it finds—this is usually controlled by the `remote.origin.fetch` configuration entries—update some set of remote-tracking branches, and create or update some of your tags.  If you are configured as a fetch mirror, with your update refspec being `+refs/*:refs/*`, you get literally everything.  Note that this refspec has the force flag set, and brings over all branches, all tags, all remote-tracking branches, and all notes.  There are more obscure details about what refspecs get used when, but using `--tags`, with or without `--force`, does not override the configuration entries (whereas writing an explicit set of refspecs does, so this is one way—maybe the only way—`--tags` differs from writing out `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`).

Updates in your own reference space—your own remote-tracking branches and tags, usually—*do* matter, but ... not for `pull`, as we'll see in the next section.

#### `git pull`

I like to say that `git pull` just runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, where the second command defaults to `git merge` unless you instruct it to use `git rebase`.  This is true and correct, but there is an obscure detail in the way.  This was easier to say before `git fetch` was rewritten as C code: back when it was a script you could follow the script's `git fetch` and `git merge` commands and see what the actual arguments were.

When `git pull` runs either `git merge` or `git rebase`, it *does not use* your remote-tracking branches and tags.  Instead, it uses the records left behind in `FETCH_HEAD`.

If you examine the examples above, you will see that they tell us that initially, `refs/heads/master` in the repository on `git.kernel.org` pointed to commit `e05806d...`.  After I ran `git fetch --tags`, the new `FETCH_HEAD` file tells us that `refs/heads/master` in the repository on `git.kernel.org` pointed (at the time I ran `fetch`, it may have changed by now) to commit `d7dffce...`.

*When `git pull` runs `git merge` or `git rebase`, it passes these raw SHA-1 numbers through.*  So it does not matter what your reference *names* resolve to.  The `git fetch` I ran did in fact update `origin/master`:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master
d7dffce1cebde29a0c4b309a79e4345450bf352a
```

but even if it had not, `git pull` would pass `d7dffce1cebde29a0c4b309a79e4345450bf352a` to the second command.

So, suppose you were fetching tags without `--force` and got object `1234567...`.  Suppose further that, had you been fetching tags *with* force, this would be the result of `git rev-parse refs/tags/last-build`, but because you did *not* use `--force`, your own repository left `last-build` pointing to `8888888...` (a very lucky commit in China :-) ).  If you, personally, say "tell me about `last-build`" you will get revision `8888888...`.  But `git pull` knows that it got `1234567...` and no matter what else happens, it will just pass the number `1234567...` to its second command, if something calls for that.

Again, it gets that number out of `FETCH_HEAD`.  So what matter here are the (full) contents of `FETCH_HEAD`, which are determined by whether you fetch with `-a` / `--append`, or not.  You only need/want `--append` in special cases that won't apply here (when you are fetching from multiple separate repositories, or fetching in separate steps for debugging purposes, or some such).

#### Of course, it does matter later

If you want / need your `last-build` tag to get updated, you will have to run `git fetch --tags --force` at some point—and now we get into atomicity issues.

Suppose that you have run `git fetch`, with or without `--tags` and with or without `--force`, perhaps by running `git pull` which runs `git fetch` without `--tags`.  You now have commit `1234567...` locally, and the name `last-build` points to either `8888888...` (not updated) or `1234567...` (updated).  Now you run `git fetch --tags --force` to update everything.  It's possible that *now*, the remote has moved `last-build` yet again.  If so, you'll get the *new* value, and update your local tag.

It's possible, with this sequence, that you never saw `8888888...`.  You might have a branch that incorporates that commit, but not know that commit by that tag—and now that you *are* updating your tags, you won't know `8888888...` by that tag *now*, either.  Is that good, bad, or indifferent?  That's up to you.

#### Avoiding `git pull`

Since `git pull` merely runs `git fetch` followed by a second command, you can just run `git fetch` yourself, followed by the second command.  This gives you full control over the `fetch` step, and lets you avoid a redundant fetch.

Since you *do* control the `fetch` step, you can specify precisely, using refspecs, just what you want updated.  Now it's time to visit the weird hybrid tag update mechanism as well.

Take any repository you have handy and run `git ls-remote`.  This will show you what it is that `git fetch` sees when it connects:

```
$ git ls-remote | head
From git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
3313b78c145ba9212272b5318c111cde12bfef4a    HEAD
ad36dc8b4b165bf9eb3576b42a241164e312d48c    refs/heads/maint
3313b78c145ba9212272b5318c111cde12bfef4a    refs/heads/master
af746e49c281f2a2946222252a1effea7c9bcf8b    refs/heads/next
6391604f1412fd6fe047444931335bf92c168008    refs/heads/pu
aa3afa0b4ab4f07e6b36f0712fd58229735afddc    refs/heads/todo
d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0
3d654be48f65545c4d3e35f5d3bbed5489820930    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0^{}
33682a5e98adfd8ba4ce0e21363c443bd273eb77    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1
729ffa50f75a025935623bfc58d0932c65f7de2f    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1^{}
```

Your Git gets, from the remote Git, a list of all references and their targets.  For references that are (annotated) tags, this includes the tag object's final target as well: that's the `gitgui-0.10.0^{}` here.  This syntax represents a *peeled* tag (see [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), though it does not use the word "peeled" here).

Your Git then, by default, brings over every *branch*—everything named `refs/heads/*`—by asking for the commits to which they point, and any additional commits and other objects needed to complete those commits.  (You do not have to download objects you already have, only those you lack-but-need.)  Your Git can then look through all the peeled tags to see if any of the tags points to one of those commits.  If so, your Git takes—with or without `--force` mode, depending on your fetch—the given tag.  If that tag points to a tag object, rather than directly to a commit, your Git adds that tag object to the collection as well.

In Git versions before 1.8.2, Git mistakenly applies the branch rules to *pushed* tag updates: they are allowed without `--force` as long as the result is a fast-forward.  That is, the previous tag target would merely need to be an ancestor of the new tag target.  This only affects lightweight tags, obviously, and in any case Git versions 1.8.2 and higher have "never replace a tag without `--force`" behavior on *push*.  Yet the observed behavior for Git 2.10.x and 2.11.x is that tags get replaced on fetch, when using `--tags`.

But no matter what, if your goal is to forcibly update all tags *and* all remote-tracking branches in the usual way, `git fetch --tags --force --prune` will do it; or you can `git fetch --prune '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'`, which uses the `+` syntax to force both tag and remote-tracking branch updates.  (The `--prune` is optional as usual.)  The force flag *may* be unnecessary, but is at least harmless here, and might do something useful in some Git versions.  And now that your tags and remote-tracking branches are updated, you can use `git merge` or `git rebase` with no arguments at all, to merge or rebase using the current branch's configured upstream.  You can repeat this for as many branches as you like, never needing to run `git pull` (with its redundant `fetch`) at all.

Comment: AFAIK (and tested with git 2.11.0), `git fetch --tags` will always update local tags, even without `--force`.

Comment: @LeGEC: interesting. Testing shows the same behavior on 2.10.1. Yet, the built in refspec that `--tags` adds does not have the force bit set (it's pre-parsed; see `s_tag_refspec` in `remote.c`). On rereading the documentation, I see another quirk: an explicit refspec subjects tags to `--prune` but `--tags` supposedly does not. (It's not at all clear how this works from the source code.)

Comment: I haven't traced the whole execution path of `fetch --tags` in the code, but you can look at all places where the value of the `tags` option (in `fetch.c`) is checked, or hard coded rules about refs starting with `refs/tags/`. Tags and branches are not handled the same way.

Comment: I did in fact look at all that code, and still can't see where tags effectively force the update. The code gets quite odd in places though, with local and remote refs looking like they're swapped at one point for instance. There are separate hardcoded rules for `push` vs `fetch`, to allow fast-forward of branches during push but not allow motion of tags during push, too. It's pretty wild in there. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the order : any order works (it commutes).

---

A note on the commands you run :

- `git fetch --tags` will already "force update" your local tags
- the `--force` option only applies to refspecs which do not start with the `+` option
- `git pull --tags origin mybranch` will apply all you want in one go (get all tags, and update your local branch)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer the following question (which you did not explicitly ask) :

> How can I update automatically a fixed set of tags each time I call `git fetch` or `git pull` ?

We have the exact same situation at my place, and this is how I delt with it .

By default, the refspec for a remote is :

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@server:repo # or whatever
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This is why it only fetches *branches* from the remote - it only gets `refs/heads/*` references from the remote.

This is the default configuration, but you can add whatever references you see fit.

---

You can use the refspec to tell git to also fetch `refs/tags/last-build` from the remote, and to automatically update your local tag :

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@server:repo # or whatever
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/last-build:refs/tags/last-build
    # this line tells :
    #   - get the 'refs/tags/last-build' (first ref, before ':') from the remote
    #   - store it in my local tag (second ref after, ':')
    #   - allow forced updates (initial '+')
```

*warning* : this specific line will trash your local `last-build` tag on each fetch, and git does not keep a reflog for tags. Given the meaning of such tags, I find this behavior ok.

If you feel uncomfortable with this, you can specify another local ref :

```
 # you will see two tags 'last-build' and 'origin/last-build' in your repo :
 fetch = +refs/tags/last-build:refs/tags/origin/last-build
```

Obviously, add one such line for each relevant tag ...

---

reference : [refspec doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)

Comment: That non-asked problem is resolved with `git fetch --tags --force` without additional configuration. The question is whether such a fetch should be done after or before the pull.

So far as I understand, with your configuration the extra fetch would be no needed right ? because that would affect also the pull. 

Anyway the question is still using the fetch .. --force... should the fetch go first or after ?

Comment: (answering your comment some years later ...) The thing with `git fetch --tags` is that it will download all remote tags, and will force update *all* your local tags to these values. Maybe this is not what you want. This answer describes a way to force update only the tags you choose to.